# move div in or out other div

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I want to add a condition when I move a blue div. Its place can't be on border, I would like it outside or inside the other div.

code :

```
$("#surface").droppable({
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            x = ui.helper.clone(false);
            x.draggable({
                helper: 'original',
                containment: '#surface',
                tolerance: 'fit'
            });
            x.find('.ui-resizable-handle').remove();
            x.resizable({
                //maxHeight: 60,
                minHeight: 60,
                minWidth: 50
            });
            x.appendTo('#surface');

            ui.helper.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

[image: exemple]

Comment: can you pleases make a jsfiddle for better understading ?

Comment: are you expecting this http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/q5mozp3b/ ?

Comment: i hope this is not suitable in you scenario. http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/q5mozp3b/1/

Comment: this my code http://fiddle.jshell.net/60f30bwr/

Comment: you can see image example

Answer (score 0):

You can you the below code.

```js
$('.drop').droppable({
  tolerance: 'intersect',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var drop_p = $(this).offset();
    var drag_p = ui.draggable.offset();
    var left_end = drop_p.left - drag_p.left + 1;
    var top_end = drop_p.top - drag_p.top + 1;
    ui.draggable.animate({
      top: '+=' + top_end,
      left: '+=' + left_end
    });
  }
});

$('.boxArt').draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',
  scroll: false,
  stack: ".boxArt"
});
```

```css
.drop {
  width: 155px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #0C5F8B;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 34px;
  float: left;
}
.boxArt {
  width: 155px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #CCC;
}
.red {
  background: #f00;
}
.green {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="boxArt red">DRAG ME</div>
<div class="drop"></div>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/q5mozp3b/

Comment: this solution requires me to put the red tile only in the div , but I want in my program or it is strictly in the div or he moves like he wants the rest of the area.
http://fiddle.jshell.net/60f30bwr/

Comment: 'table' is moving over the entire 'surface' or in motion in the 'zone' and will not be on the border

Comment: like image in question

Answer (score -1):

For Multiple div below code may help you.

HTML

```
<div class="Dreggable_div red">DRAG ME</div>
<div class="dropbox1 mybox"></div>
<div class="dropbox2 mybox"></div>
<div class="dropbox3 mybox"></div>
```

CSS

```
.mybox{
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #0C5F8B;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:34px;
    float:left;
}
.Dreggable_div{
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background:#CCC;
}
.red {
    background: #f00;
}
.green {
    background: #0f0;
}
```

JS

```
$('.dropbox1 , .dropbox2, .dropbox3').droppable({
    tolerance: 'intersect',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var drop_p = $(this).offset();
        var drag_p = ui.draggable.offset();
        var left_end = drop_p.left - drag_p.left + 1;
        var top_end = drop_p.top - drag_p.top + 1;
        ui.draggable.animate({
            top: '+=' + top_end,
            left: '+=' + left_end
        });
    }
});

$('.Dreggable_div').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    scroll: false,
    stack: ".Dreggable_div"
});
```